# R merging data based on nearest date and under fulfilled condition

Tags: r, date, join, merge

I want to do a left join with two data.frames by df1$plots = df2$plots AND the nearest date.
Some plot numbers of both data.frames also repeat, like in this example:

```
df1=data.frame(plots=c(1,2,3,4,1),dates=as.POSIXct(c('01.01.2021','01.02.2021','01.03.2021','01.04.2021','02.01.2021'),format='%d.%m.%Y'))

df1
  plots      dates
1     1 2021-01-01
2     2 2021-02-01
3     3 2021-03-01
4     4 2021-04-01
5     1 2021-01-02

df2=data.frame(plots=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),dates=as.POSIXct(c('05.01.2021','02.02.2021','01.01.2021','29.03.2021','31.12.2020','17.06.2021','05.03.2021','08.02.2021'),format='%d.%m.%Y'),TargetValues=c(100:107) )

df2
  plots      dates TargetValues
1     1 2021-01-05          100
2     2 2021-02-02          101
3     3 2021-01-01          102
4     4 2021-03-29          103
5     1 2020-12-31          104
6     2 2021-06-17          105
7     3 2021-03-05          106
8     4 2021-02-08          107
```

I would like df1 to look like this in the end:

```
  plots      dates Values
1     1 2021-01-01    104
2     2 2021-02-01    101
3     3 2021-03-01    106
4     4 2021-04-01    103
5     1 2021-01-02    104
```

This is what I tried:

```
df1.2 <- lapply(intersect(df1$plots,df2$plots,function(id) {
  d1 <- subset(df1,plots==id)
  d2 <- subset(df2,plots==id)
  
  d1$indices <- sapply(d1$date,function(d) which.min(abs(d2$date - d)))
  d2$indices <- 1:nrow(d2)
  
  merge(d1,d2,by=c('plots','indices'))
}))
```

But I get an error saying "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default".

How can I fix the code or does somebody have a different idea how do the task?

Answer (score 2):

You can join the two dataframes by `plots` and for each value of plots and dates select the row which has the lowest absolute difference.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by = 'plots') %>%
  group_by(plots, dates.x) %>%
  slice(which.min(abs(dates.x - dates.y))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(plots, dates = dates.x, TargetValues)

#  plots dates               TargetValues
#  <dbl> <dttm>                     <int>
#1     1 2021-01-01 00:00:00          104
#2     1 2021-01-02 00:00:00          104
#3     2 2021-02-01 00:00:00          101
#4     3 2021-03-01 00:00:00          106
#5     4 2021-04-01 00:00:00          103
```

Comment: Thank you! After I did that, the rows of my target data frame decreased from 292 to 177. Do you know why and how to fix that? Edit: I changed the select (...) at the end to select_all, because I want to see all the data from all the rows

Comment: Do you have `NA`'s in `plots` or `dates` column of `df1` ? Also if you remove the `select` statement al together it would select all the columns.

Comment: Yes, there are `NA`s in `plots`. I have removed the select statement and ended with `ungroup`, but the rows are still decreasing. Can I just skip, when `NA`s appear?

Comment: The decreasement happens after the `slice()` argument